# How to save objects en la UpdateView class, returning a Json?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have 2 related models for an fk and to which I access. But to save the instances of the forms in the UpdateView class, I get the error "AttributeError: type object 'Users_up' has no attribute 'object'
[10 / Oct / 2019 15:18:17] "POST / PermissionUpdateView / 3 / HTTP / 1.1" 500 "and don't let me save with the post help method please, what am I wrong?

viws.py

```
class PermisoUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Permiso
    second_model = Users
    template_name = 'plantillas/permisos_update.html'
    form_class = Permiso_update
    second_form_class = Users_up


    def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
        context =super(PermisoUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', 0)
        p = self.model.objects.get(id=pk)
        u = self.second_model.object.get(id=p.usuario_id)
        if 'form' not in context:
        context['form'] = self.form_class(instance=p)
        if 'form2' not in context:
        context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(instance=u)
        context['id'] = pk
        return context

    def post(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object
        id_Permiso = kwargs['pk']
        per = self.model.objects.get(id=id_Permiso)
        us = self.second_form_class.object.get(id=per.usuario_id)
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=per)
        form2 = self.second_form_class(request.POST, instance=us)
        if form.is_valid and form2.is_valid and request.is_ajax():
            form.save()
            form2.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status':'true', 'msg':'Datos procesados correctamente'})#retornando JSon en jsConsole 
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'false', 'msg':'Datos procesados incorrectamente'})#retornando respuesta en jsConsole
```

Comment: This is all a bit strange. Forms are not models, they don't have managers. And even for models, the manager is called `objects`, not `object`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hi is same objects or object the console send me the same error 
in addition to django.db.utils.IntegrityError: la columna 'usuario_id' no puede ser nula
[10 / Oct / 2019 15:42:17] "POST / PermisoUpdateView / 1 / HTTP / 1.1" 500 22802